# Gensim LDA All coefficients are NaN for more than 70 topics

Tags: python, gensim, lda, topic-modeling

I am currently running LDA on my dataset. The dataset consists of approximately 60k Documents. The documents are approximately as long as a Wikipedia article. 
I ran LDA for 10,20,30...,70 Topics fine. For 80 and more Topics, all coefficients turn to nan. I tried every combination of numpy and gensim version on two different computers but I get the same result on both.
I have absolutely no idea how to solve this problem. Please let me know what info you need.

Since you asked for a code snippet here is the line for the lda:

`lda = gensim.models.ldamulticore.LdaMulticore(corpus, 
    id2word=dictionary, num_topics=80, chunksize=1800, passes=20, 
    workers=1, eval_every=1, iterations=1000)`

I changed the number of workers. Normally I used 3 or 4.

Comment: could you provide some code snippets

Comment: I edited the original post.